# 20% CPU usage when completely idle in RDS MySQL5.7 T3.xlarge instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds

I'm currently using MySQL 5.7 RDS `T3.xlarge instance(4 vCPU and 16G RAM)` but have 20% CPU usage when the instance is idle completely. There is no any running queries and functions or triggers at all.

Just there is only a RDS process(I guess it's used on RDS side for CloudWatch metrics).

I have around 6000 tables and these are frequently dropped and created on a daily basis. Also there is a mysql View that contains these tables. I think this is not related to SQL I use since there's no any running queries.

Please help me if you had same problem. Thank you.

> UPDATE - Here is the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output.

```
=====================================
2020-07-22 15:28:53 0x2aafd0586700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 5 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1330801 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 811 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1331382
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 17366635
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 16791462
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 2860683, OS waits 1363178
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 28207715, OS waits 905468
RW-sx spins 82417, rounds 1100277, OS waits 31207
Spin rounds per wait: 2860683.00 RW-shared, 28207715.00 RW-excl, 13.35 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 3809183313
Purge done for trx's n:o < 3809183041 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 43
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 328409603382496, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603381576, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603380656, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603379736, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603378816, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603377896, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 328409603376976, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
20597537 OS file reads, 43614541 OS file writes, 15755878 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 7587, seg size 7589, 5062567 merges
merged operations:
 insert 22116890, delete mark 20922, delete 9398
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 5508 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 5000 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 4728 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 4690 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 5610 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 3606 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 5047 buffer(s)
Hash table size 5839637, node heap has 7705 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 3.60 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 2141555820704
Log flushed up to   2141555820704
Pages flushed up to 2141555820704
Last checkpoint at  2141555820695
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
6788595 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 12085231616
Dictionary memory allocated 59861350
Buffer pool size   720384
Free buffers       803
Database pages     677687
Old database pages 249998
Modified db pages  88369
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 13780732, not young 2059574639
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 20584036, created 2839117, written 32590403
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 677687, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[64]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84681
Old database pages 31239
Modified db pages  11068
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1738769, not young 262274165
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2589559, created 360435, written 5406809
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84681, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84681
Old database pages 31239
Modified db pages  11074
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1704348, not young 247366083
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2568576, created 356237, written 3049119
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84681, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84760
Old database pages 31268
Modified db pages  11076
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1735284, not young 246122000
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2549553, created 355362, written 3226658
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84760, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84763
Old database pages 31269
Modified db pages  11074
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1717134, not young 256516506
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2611069, created 347215, written 5194167
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84763, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84686
Old database pages 31241
Modified db pages  11061
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1730814, not young 279472374
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2586632, created 360314, written 5222435
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84686, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       100
Database pages     84688
Old database pages 31241
Modified db pages  10972
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1730874, not young 248283848
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2566160, created 353796, written 3107025
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84688, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       102
Database pages     84734
Old database pages 31258
Modified db pages  11017
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1702405, not young 242040513
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2566906, created 356646, written 2731905
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84734, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   90048
Free buffers       101
Database pages     84694
Old database pages 31243
Modified db pages  11027
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1721104, not young 277499150
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 2545581, created 349112, written 4652285
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 84694, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[8]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=8037, Main thread ID=46960771868416, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 624068542, updated 7392450, deleted 2477522, read 26669457143
23.20 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 23.20 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: Could we use Skype to Talk about your 88,369 dirty pages and the last few lines of the 
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; report?

My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com    (Birmingham  AL)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe no actions are occuring I would suggest enabling [RDS Performance Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/performance-insights/).

By enabling this you should be provided a breakdown of the load that your DB is receiving and might help you to see a visual breakdown of any SQL actions not considered.

If there are no actions that you can see after a decent length of time try giving the RDS node a reboot. If this does not resolve it try contacting AWS support to help you understand.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I've already enabled performance Insights and there's no any actions are occuring. After rebooting instance, it's pretty good for 2 or 3 days but finally same as before after 3 days.

Comment: Do you happen to have a large number of connections left alive (potentially they were never closed)?

Comment: No. there are only few connections(about 5 connections) and wait_timeout or interactive_timeout is pretty short. In my case it's 100

Comment: Hmm thats definitely odd. Presumably there are no processes deadlocked etc?

Comment: Interesting... How can I check it?

Comment: Try running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` and look for processes that have a status of `Locked`

Comment: There's no any processes except two RDS admin processes. they're currently sleep status but it doesn't exceed 10 seconds

Comment: Hmm ok, if theres no processes there then something strange is happening, I would say raise with AWS and see what they come back with for the moment. You've gone through steps to identify any activity and found none so it might be an underlying host issue

Comment: Hmm ok, if theres no processes there then something strange is happening, I would say raise with AWS and see what they come back with for the moment. You've gone through steps to identify any activity and found none so it might be an underlying host issue

Comment: @AlexandrBiship Please post TEXT result of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%dirty%'; and B) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to pastebin.com to avoid filling up this question.  Share the links with us, please.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck, Thanks. there is the link. https://pastebin.com/9mEm4sTL

Comment: @AlexandrBiship The above link is not functional at this time.  Attach output to email to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com  please.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship Did you overcome this trouble?  If not, please repost to pastebin the items requested Jul 22 2020 at 14:17. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the options that you can try is to change [RDS instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/instance-types/) from `t3` to `r` or `z` these are next-generation RDS instance. If you still see `20%` usage on ideal state then its something that will need further investigation but before going to dig further better to check with the next generation RDS.

> I have around 6000 tables and these are frequently dropped and created on a daily basis.

So, there is enough DML operation so if we can not ignore this contribution as well to CPU usage and we can check processlist in the background

> `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` - see what is happening inside of InnoDB. Under `'TRANSACTIONS'` you should see your killed staetment being rolled back.

[mysqld constant CPU usage when absolutly nothing is connected and no queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68972/167146)

[How can I troubleshoot and resolve high CPU utilization on my Amazon RDS for MySQL, MariaDB, or Aurora for MySQL instances?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-instance-high-cpu/)

Also there are **many threads on AWS forums that experience an issue with `T` type** instances.

[20-cpu-usage-by-rds-instance-when-idle](https://serverfault.com/questions/737769/20-cpu-usage-by-rds-instance-when-idle)

[t2-medium 100% usage](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164532)

[RDS instance spiking to 50% CPU usage for sustained period](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=169893)

[RDS instance idle on 70+% CPU Utilization](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=928800)

Comment: Thank you @Adiii, Could you please check my innodb status output. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a solution but could be helpful for someone who have similar problem like me. Recently I've subscribed for reserved instance for above MySQL instance and CPU usage suddenly goes stable(1 ~ 2% when idle) and it's fairly good which is I expected. There's no any code changes in backend side and MySQL configuration etc. Not sure this only happened for me and Amazon issue or something is going to wrong way in internal process on MySQL side